# Of all those OR from all those

Tags: prepositions

Could you explain why we use OF and FROM in the following sentences and why we can't use them vice versa?

**From** all those applying for the position, Mr. Jamison was the one chosen, as he was the most experienced."

**Of** all of those applying, Mr. Jamison was the most experienced one.

Comment: Where is the "closing team", I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your sentences are correct. You only need to rearrange them to see why one uses "from" and the other uses "or":

> Mr Jamison was the one **chosen from** all those applying for the position as he was the most experienced.

If someone is chosen, they are picked out *from* among the others.

> Mr Jamison was **the most experienced of all** of those applying.

This singles out Mr Jamison but in a different way - it compares him *to* the other candidates. For this comparison, he remains part of the group.